# Unable to access the data in the gird tile in angular using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a sample application in angular using the angular material grid component.

When I am placing my data values inside **ngOnInit(){}** , I am unable to fetch the data and I am getting an error

```
"Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Tile[]'."
```

Can anybody please suggest me what am I missing out here...?

Please access my [sample app here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-r4s19h?file=app%2Fgridlist.component.ts)

Anybody please help me out with this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

`this.tiles = data`